# Slack outgoing webhook :URL(s)

Tags: slack-api, slack

Can anyone please explain the URL(s) in slack outgoing webhooks configurations?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The URLs in outgoing webhooks are locations that you control where, when certain conditions are met, Slack's servers will send a HTTP POST to the URL with the data described in the [outgoing webhooks](https://api.slack.com/outgoing-webhooks) docs and you'll have a chance to respond with a simple messsage.

You'll need a server or service that is reachable by Slack to work with outgoing webhooks. Here's another [good overview of outgoing webhooks](http://www.programmableweb.com/news/how-to-integrate-webhooks-slack-api/how-to/2015/10/20?page=2).