# Slack outgoing webhook post what type of post request is it?

Tags: php, apache, webhooks, slack

I'm not sure if I'm understanding what slack means by a post request.

In my experience with what I'm familiar with it's either a curl request POST or with PHP use something like:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
  // get token
  $token = $_POST['token'];
}
```

I'm not receiving anything from Slack though, Is it a cors problem? I tried that I enabled headers. I saw other questions, I can't seem to find much on this topic.

[how to handle outgoing-webhook (Slack) using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42419340/how-to-handle-outgoing-webhook-slack-using-php)

[Slack outgoing webhook :URL(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38092062/slack-outgoing-webhook-urls)

I selected a channel, I also put in a trigger word, the return text is not related to the trigger word. Maybe by returning the text it's triggering/causing a loop? I just tried that no dice as well. There are no errors in apache, the code itself works, when I visit the link directly on my server it processes the code.

The incoming webhooks are no problem.

I don't understand I've tried this many times could never get it to work what am I missing?

Regarding the headers I wasn't sure what domain to match to, I didn't enable all (the star *) so I tried slack.com but it's possible that's not what slack uses to send out the request.

Answer (score 0):

I am also learning on this, and there's not much documentation anywhere. I tried it yesterday. I sent a text with trigger words like "try send abcd". Based on the posted data to my public URL it will match the trigger word try with text "try send abcd". This text will be posted to the URL I provide in configuration and I catch the posted data like what's slack described in their docs with api response json raw body.

Anyway, the channel and url provided must be public and you need to provide a trigger words too. what's the posted data sent to your URL?

So far that's what I can do. I also plan to fetch them via js fetch(). if you've got any information on this kindly share it with me :)

Comment: What are you using server side (unless that is js fetch?) I'm a LAMP stack myself at this time so I use PHP. I couldn't get anything as far as I could tell from the post request I sent. I wasn't sure how to tell if it was working, I suppose I could just create an insert/logger to see if the post request is received. Thanks for the info, hope you get yours figured out. It would be a nice feature to have as the incoming webhooks are no problem.

Comment: What did you mean by this: This text will be posted to the URL? Why the url? If it's URL then should I use GET perhaps or parse the url I wonder.

Comment: I'm using apache phalcon mongo env. so you're using a localhost right? I connected the localhost as server to slack using ngrok and the posted data will be visible when i run my project inside ngrok.
The URL is url you provide in outgoing webhook configuration. The posted data will be sent to that URL, as far as I know, the data sent using HTTP POST, so I get the response by api handler via POST

Comment: Thanks. Yes it'll be great if it's supported by slack apps.

Comment: Maybe there is a slack forum should check, they have that app community haven't checked that out myself.